# Using arrayfun to apply two arguments of a function on every combination

Tags: octave, vectorization

Let `i = [1 2]` and `j = [3 5]`. Now in octave:

```
arrayfun(@(x,y) x+y,i,j)
```

we get `[4 7]`. But I want to apply the function on the combinations of `i` vs. `j` to get `[i(1)+j(1) i(1)+j(2) i(2)+j(1) i(2)+j(2)]=[4 6 5 7]`.

How do I accomplish this? I know I can go with for-loopsl but I want vectorized-code because it's faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Octave, for finding summations between two vectors, you can use a truly vectorized approach with [`broadcasting`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Broadcasting.html) like so -

```
out = reshape(ii(:).' + jj(:),[],1)
```

Here's a runtime test on [`ideone`](http://ideone.com/C0DrAM) for the input vectors of size `1 x 100` each -

```
-------------------- With FOR-LOOP
Elapsed time is 0.148444 seconds.
-------------------- With BROADCASTING
Elapsed time is 0.00038299 seconds.
```

If you want to keep it generic to accommodate operations other than just summations, you can use anonymous functions like so -

```
func1 = @(I,J) I+J;
out = reshape(func1(ii,jj.'),1,[])
```

---

In MATLAB, you could accomplish the same with two [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) alternatives as listed next.

I. `bsxfun` with Anonymous Function -

```
func1 = @(I,J) I+J;
out = reshape(bsxfun(func1,ii(:).',jj(:)),1,[]);
```

II. `bsxfun` with Built-in @plus -

```
out = reshape(bsxfun(@plus,ii(:).',jj(:)),1,[]);
```

With the input vectors of size `1 x 10000` each, the runtimes at my end were -

```
-------------------- With FOR-LOOP
Elapsed time is 1.193941 seconds.
-------------------- With BSXFUN ANONYMOUS
Elapsed time is 0.252825 seconds.
-------------------- With BSXFUN BUILTIN
Elapsed time is 0.215066 seconds.
```

Comment: your solutions are fast , though they still don't work with 1:1e5 arrays, it should be enough

Comment: @niceman Yeah that's one thing with vectorization because it works with everything in one-go, one needs to have enough memory to accommodate everything.

Answer (score 1):

First, your first example is not the best because the most efficient way to accomplish what you're doing with [`arrayfun`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Function-Application.html) would be to vectorize:

```
a = [1 2];
b = [3 5];
out = a+b
```

Second, in Matlab at least, `arrayfun` is not necessarily faster than a simple `for` loop. `arrayfun` is mainly a convenience (especially for it's more advanced options). Try this simple timing example yourself:

```
a = 1:1e5;
b = a+1;

y = arrayfun(@(x,y)x+y,a,b); % Warm up
tic
y = arrayfun(@(x,y)x+y,a,b);
toc

y = zeros(1,numel(a));
for k = 1:numel(a)
    y(k) = a(k)+b(k); % Warm up
end
tic
y = zeros(1,numel(a));
for k = 1:numel(a)
    y(k) = a(k)+b(k);
end
toc
```

In Matlab R2015a, the `for` loop method is over 70 times faster run from the Command window and over 260 times faster when run from an M-file function. Octave may be different, but you should experiment.

Finally, you can accomplish what you want using [`meshgrid`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/meshgrid.html):

```
a = [1 2];
b = [3 5];
[x,y] = meshgrid(a,b);
out = x(:).'+y(:).'
```

which returns `[4 6 5 7]` as in your question. You can also use [`ndgrid`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/ndgrid.html) to get output in a different order.

Comment: thanks, just correct the typo 'k is undefined' in the for loop body

Comment: well in octave both arrayfun and for-loop are almost the same time , anyway your point is good, arrayfun is not faster than for-loop

Comment: @niceman: I'd guess that some of the difference between Matlab and Octave he may come down to due [JIT compilation](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/237478).

Comment: well your solution worked but not for a=1:1e5,b=a+1. it said "Out of memory or dimension is too large"

Comment: Not surprised. I only used those example `a` and `b` for the timing example. `meshgrid` takes advantage of [space-time tradeoff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-time_tradeoff). It would require at least `2*N^2` array elements (where `N` is the length of `a` and `b`). For `N = 1e5`  doubles you'd need about 150 GB of memory. Hopefully your real data is much smaller.

Comment: hmmm my real data is an image data

Comment: @niceman: If you're doing this for all of the pixels of anything but the smallest of images, you should probably look into the combinatorics of your problem/approach. You may have memory issues regardless.